# python substring is out of range

Tags: python, string

I am reading a message from serial. It is working fine.

If I use this code, it works

```
while 1:
        data_raw=ser.read(33).decode('ascii')
        if len(data_raw) > 0:
                print(data_raw[0])
```

OUTPUT

```
===== RESTART: C:\Users\...=====
S
S
S
S
S
```

But if I use this code, it doesn't work

```
while 1:
        data_raw=ser.read(33).decode('ascii')
        if data_raw[0] is 'S':
                print(data_raw[0])
```

OUTPUT

```
    if data_raw[0] is 'S':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: `if len(data_raw) > 0 and data_raw[0] is 'S':`

Comment: Thanks you! Now it is working like a charm :D

Comment: @EdwardMinnix because I dont remember this condition necessary for the IF  statement "len(data_raw) > 0"  in a substring :D

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you properly check the length of the `data_raw` list before accessing any item of it.

Whereas, in your second item you test a condition on the first item of data_raw  `if data_raw[0] is 'S':` but you have to make sure this item is actually defined.

Here, Python tells you there is no `data_raw[0]`. You need to make sure `len(data_raw) > 0` before accessing `data_raw[0]`.

Comment: I need to check the first element of the message because it has 33 bytes and the first element is a 'S'. After I can do a fix substring code to store each segment in a database. The target is something like datalogging from serial port over ethernet (it is another part of future code)